# Prove that $-(ab) = a(-b)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

> Prove that $$-(ab) = a(-b)$$

*Proof:*

We need to show that $$a(-b) + ab = 0$$
which is equivalent to
$$\begin{align}
a(-b)+ ab &= 0 \\
a(-b+b) &= 0 \\
a(0) &= 0 
\end{align}$$

Q.E.D

I would like to have some feedback on the proof. Thanks.

Comment: You're doing the necessary steps to get the proof. Now you just need to write it in the reverse order, starting with $a(0)=0$. But is this true? Why? Really, you're trying to show "For any $a$ and for any $b$, we have ..." that equality. So you start with "Let $a,b$ be arbitrary. Then..."

Comment: @ndhanson3 There is no need to "reverse" the order. The proof of the type "We show that $a(-b) + ab$ is equal to $a\cdot 0$ which is equal to $0$" is perfectly fine.

Comment: I agree. Nothing is wrong with the proof. I would add some explanation of what is happening. It would also be clearer if OP would omitt the $0$ and worked their way to $0$ instead, as your comment suggests.

Comment: $a(-b)+ ab = a(-b+b)=a(0) =0$

Answer (score 2):

Moving my comment to an answer and expanding a bit.

You're doing the necessary steps to get the proof. Now you just need to write it in reverse order, starting with $a(0)=0$. But is this true? Why?

Really, you're trying to show "For any $a$ and for any $b$, we have ..." that equality.

So the proof could resemble:

> Let $a$ be arbitrary. Then by _____, we have $$a(0)=0.$$ Now let $b$ be arbitrary. By _____, we have $-b+b=0,$ and substituting into the above equation, we obtain $$a(-b+b)=0.$$
> ...

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct. You just have to understand what you are doing. You know that for $a \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $a.0 = 0$ because $a.0 = a (0 + 0) = a.0 + a.0$. By the uniqueness of the neuter element of the sum we obtain $a.0 = 0$ . Now, for any real number $b$ we have $b-b = 0$. Therefore $0 = a.0 = a (b-b) = ab + a (-b)$. why?

Answer (score 0):

I would do the proof as follows:
Let $a, b \in R$, your ring.

From an earlier result we know that:
$a \cdot 0=0$  (so multiplication by the additive identity element results in the additive identity)
If you do not know this, prove it first (hint $0=0+0$).

Next we rewrite this using $b+-b=0$. This gives:
$$a(b+-b)=0.$$
We apply the distributive law:
$$ab + a(-b) =0$$
Now observe that this condition means that $a(-b)$ is the inverse of $ab$. Normally we would write this as $-ab$. By uniqueness of inverses we know that $a(-b)= -ab$  $\square$.

It is best practice to explain your reasoning and which laws/axioms you apply in between steps. Your original proof consisted of symbolic manipulation. You have to think and argue "why" your steps are true.